# C# Radio buttons: how can I assign two values to a single radio button. One text value for front-end user, and the other ID value for the program

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I am dynamically creating a set of radio buttons based on the results in a SQL table. The SQL results are being stored in a data table; there are two columns, one for client IDs and the other for client name. Whenever the user activates this form, they should only see client name, but when they click ok, the ID value needs to be returned to a variable.

I am currently only passing in the Client_Name field from the table. How can I return the ID value of a client name? Is it possible to assign to two values to each individual button?

Code that is creating the buttons:

```
//radio button array is initially set in the designer.cs file.
public System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[] radioButtons { get; set; }
```

```
 public Clients()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            //Call connectDatabase method from ContractSearch
            ContractSearch con = new ContractSearch();
            string database = "dbo";
            string query = @"select distinct 
                                client_id
                                ,client_name
                            from
                                tbl_Clients";
            DataTable result = con.connectToDatabase(database, query);
            int client_row = result.Select().Length;

            radioButtons = new RadioButton[client_row];
            Label title = new Label();
            title.Text = "Select a Client:";

            int i = 0;
            int y = 0;
            title.Location = new Point(10, 10 + y * 20);
            Controls.Add(title);
            y += 1;

            //Iterate through all rows in table, creating radio buttons for each client name value
            foreach (DataRow cell in result.Rows)
            {

                radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
                radioButtons[i].Text = cell["Client_Name"].ToString();

                radioButtons[i].Location = new Point(10, 10 + y * 20);
                Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
                i += 1;
                y += 1;
            }

            //create OK button
            Button but_ok = new Button();
            but_ok.Location = new Point(15, 10 + y * 25);
            but_ok.Text = "OK";
            Controls.Add(but_ok);
            but_ok.Click += new EventHandler(this.but_ok_Click);

        }
```

Here is the click event for the OK button. This is where I'm doing my check to determine which radio button is clicked.

```
private void but_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //lookup enumerations to pass in id values to AA screen
            foreach (RadioButton btn in radioButtons)
            {
                if(btn.Checked==false)
                {
                    continue; //skip to next loop iteration if radio button is not checked
                }
                else if(btn.Checked==true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(btn.Checked.ToString()+" "+btn.Text); //for debugging purposes
                    /*
                      store Client_ID value into but_value. This will be passed to the parent form.
                      radioButtons.Value does not serve a function. It is merely a placeholder.
                    */
                    but_Value = radioButtons.Value;
                }
            }
         Close();
        }
```

Comment: I'm curious what `radioButtons` is?

Comment: It's the radio button array. It's setup in the deigner.cs file where the all the properties are set. I updated the post to add that in. Thanks for calling it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control's Tag may help.

```
radioButtons[i].Tag = cell["client_ID"];

Console.WriteLine("Checked button's ID is: " + btn.Tag.ToString());
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `RadioButton` inherits `Tag` from `Control`. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!